# Append n x 1 vector to n x 1 cell array

Tags: matlab, vector, concatenation, cell-array

I'm trying to append [1 2.2] to {'foo' 'ba'} and get:

```
    'foo'    'ba'               
    1        2.200000
```

I'm nearly there:

```
>> A = {'foo' 'ba'}

A =

  1×2 cell array

    'foo'    'ba'

>> b = [1 2.2]

b =

   1.000000000000000   2.200000000000000

>> [A;b]
Error using vertcat
Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are
not consistent.

>> [A;num2cell(b)]

ans =

  2×2 cell array

    'foo'    'ba'               
    [  1]    [2.200000000000000]
```

How to get rid of the []?

Comment: You are doing it right. In Matlab, `1` and `[1]` is exactly the same thing (check with `isequal(1, [1])`)

Answer (score 0):

`[A;num2cell(b)]` is the correct implementation.

You can try doing

```
[A(1);b(1)]

ans = 

    'foo'
    [  1]
```

Notice the vector b element 1 represented as [ 1] which are equalivalent.

Answer (score 0):

```
A = {'foo' 'ba'} ;
b = {'1' '2.2'} ;
[A ;b] 

or

vertcat(A,b)
```